# Handlebars.js - Each and getter

Tags: function, loops, each, handlebars.js, getter

I'm using Handlebars.js and got stuck in a problem I can't solve.

I want to iterate through an array within a template, but the problem is that the expression I'm using for the iterator is a getter and not an array.

A piece of code that illustrates the problem is the following one:

HTML:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars">
    Accessing directly: {{array}} <br/>
    Accessing by getter: {{getArray}} <br/>

    <br/>

    Looping directly:
    <ul>
    {{#each array}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <br/>

    Looping by getter:
    <ul>
    {{#each getArray}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<p id="content"></p>
```

JS:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());
var element = {
    array: [0, 1, 2],

    getArray: function() {
        return this.array;
    }
};

$("#content").html(template(element));
```

The problem is that the `each` that uses the getter does nothing. This can be seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezequielscaruli/wamWd/1/).

Is there any clean way to perform this using the getter, or should I write a helper or something like an auxiliary function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{{#each}}` expects an array and it won't understand anything else. You could add a simple custom helper for this, you'd just have to remember to use [`fn.call(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) if you expect this:

```
getArray: function() {
    return this.array;
}
```

to have the right `this`. Something like this would probably do the trick:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('smart_each', function(a, block) {
    if(typeof a == 'function')
        a = a.call(this);
    var s = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        s += block(a[i]);
    return s;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yuPfD/

You might want to look at the `{{#each}}` implementation in the Handlebars source to spruce that up a bit but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [proper JavaScript getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), your technique will work. Here's an example using classes, available in ES6. For an ES5 example of the code below, see [this version which uses babel.io's repl](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code='use%20strict'%0A%0Aconst%20handlebars%20%3D%20require('handlebars')%0Aconst%20template%20%3D%20%22%7B%7B%23each%20letters%7D%7D%20%7B%7Bthis%7D%7D%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%22%0Avar%20context%0A%0Aclass%20Alphabet%20%7B%0A%20%20get%20letters()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'abc'.split('')%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Acontext%20%3D%20new%20Alphabet()%0Aconsole.log('class%20instance%20with%20getter%20methods%3A')%0Aconsole.log(handlebars.compile(template)(context))%0A%0A%0Acontext%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20letters%3A%20'xyz'.split('')%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log('regular%20object%3A')%0Aconsole.log(handlebars.compile(template)(context))%0A).

```
'use strict'

const handlebars = require('handlebars')
const template = "{{#each letters}} {{this}} {{/each}}"
var context

class Alphabet {
  get letters() {
    return 'abc'.split('')
  }
}

context = new Alphabet()
console.log('class instance with getter methods:')
console.log(handlebars.compile(template)(context))


context = {
  letters: 'xyz'.split('')
}

console.log('regular object:')
console.log(handlebars.compile(template)(context))
```

The output:

```
❯ node index.js
class instance with getter methods:
 a  b  c 
regular object:
 x  y  z
```